# Невидимый combobox

Tags: html

Имеется `combobox`, в нём есть определённое кол-во айтемов. Можно ли сделать полностью невидимым комбобокс?

Comment: select{display:none}

Answer (score 4):

У тэга `select` есть свойство `hidden` - его значение нужно установить в позицию `true`:

```
...
<select hidden="true">
<option value="1">Один</option>
<option value="2">Два</option>
<option value="3">Три</option>
</select>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать стили для достижения необходимого результата

```
<select style="display:none;"></select>
```